# Oracle select distinct merge duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a simple table in my database which looks like this

```
+----------+-------------+
| category | category_id |
+----------+-------------+
| cars     |           1 |
| bikes    |           2 |
| planes   |           3 |
| bikes    |           4 |
| cars     |           5 |
+----------+-------------+
```

As you can see the data is not the best and there are duplicate categories with different category_ids. My goal is to get a result where each category occurs one time and if there are multiple ids for the same category name merge them (comma-separated or sth. like that). So for the example, the result should look like this

```
+----------+-------------+
| category | category_id |
+----------+-------------+
| cars     |         1,5 |
| bikes    |         2,4 |
| planes   |           3 |
+----------+-------------+
```

How can I archive that result. My current query looks like this

```
select distinct category, category_id 
from my_table
order by 1;
```

I have absolutely no idea how to archive this kind of merge with a distinct statement. Is the distinct statement the right approach or should I use another one?

Comment: `DISTINCT` cannot work here, because the `category` / `category_id` pairs are already distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right; a category ID should represent a category, so such a table should not contain the same category twice (with two different IDs). The table lacks a unique constraint on category.

You want to see the data represented differently, which you can achieve with aggregation:

```
select
  category,
  listagg(category_id, ', ') within group (order by category_id) as category_ids
from my_table
group by category
order by category;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `listagg` like

```
select category, listagg(category_id, ',') category_id
from my_table
group by category
```

see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60f77138cded2f0227845c61de1b5af4)